# Access a node of string label with an int part of the string

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using NetworkX library with Python.

I want to be able to refer to a node by using only the an int ID which is a part of the node name (string) for a variety of purposes, like getting the shortest path between two nodes.

MWE:

Let's say that I import a Pajek-formatted file:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.read_pajek("pajek_network_file.net")
G=nx.Graph(G)
```

The contents of my file are (In Pajek, nodes are called "Vertices"):

```
*Network
*Vertices 6
123 Author1
456 Author2
789 Author3
111 Author4
222 Author5
333 Author6
*Edges 
123 333
333 789
789 222
```

Which command should I use for, printing node Author4 by using only its id of 111?

So far, I've tried a format of G.node[nodeid], like:

```
print G.node[111]
```

but this returns an error, because it's trying to search for node LABEL = 111, which of course doesn't exist.

As a follow-up question, ideally I'd like not only to print a node by ID, but also to use it with functions, such as

```
nx.shortest_path_length(G,source_nodeid,target_nodeid)
```

What I'm doing as a work around for the moment is creating a .net network file with the node id column repeated twice, as to use the same id number as "node label" too.

I'm sure the answer must be very simple, but it just has escaped me so far, even after Googling a lot and going through the documentation...
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [nx.relabel_nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html) function which takes a dictionary to map old labels to new labels. I used vertices names you provided to build the graph. Then created a dictionary which maps the old labels (full string) to new labels (integer cast of the first element of the string after splitting it). Finally, I used the relabel_nodes function to do the relabelling.

Here is how I used it to solve your problem:

```
G = nx.Graph()
vertices = ['123 Author1','456 Author2','789 Author3','111 Author4','222 Author5','333 Author6']
for v in vertices:
    G.add_node(v)
# Maps old labels to new labels
new_labels = dict( (i , int(i.split()[0]) ) for i in G.nodes() )
print new_labels
# Relabel nodes
nx.relabel_nodes(G,new_labels,False)  
# To access node with integer 123 for instance
print G[123]
# Draw the network with all labels
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, node_size = 500)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In case you would like to use the old labels for drawing for example then you can have another dictionary which is the inverse of the new_lables that simply maps the new labels to the old ones. Here is how you might do so:

```
# This can be used if you want to keep the old labels for drawing purpose for instance
old_labels = dict ( (y,x) for x,y in new_labels.iteritems() )
nx.draw_networkx(G, labels = old_labels, with_labels=True, node_size = 500)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

networkx keeps the nodes and edges of the graph in a dictionary structure where the node is the key, and its data is an associated dictionary structure. Apparently when you read the pajek file format given your example file, the dictionnary is this one:

```
>>> G = nx.read_pajek("test.pj")
>>> pprint(G.node)
{u'Author1': {'id': u'123'},
 u'Author2': {'id': u'456'},
 u'Author3': {'id': u'789'},
 u'Author4': {'id': u'111'},
 u'Author5': {'id': u'222'},
 u'Author6': {'id': u'333'}}
```

Which means node `u'Author1'` is associated with data `{'id': u'123'}`

Now, I don't know in the Pajek file format which field is supposed to be the actual node (maybe it's not implemented correctly in networkx?), but if you reverse names and ids in your file you get what you want:

```
*Network
*Vertices 6
    Author1 123
    Author2 456
    Author3 789
    Author4 111
    Author5 222
    Author6 333
*Edges 
    123 333
    333 789
    789 222
```

and

```
>>> G = nx.read_pajek("test.pj")
>>> pprint(G.node)
{u'111': {'id': u'Author4'},
 u'123': {'id': u'Author1'},
 u'222': {'id': u'Author5'},
 u'333': {'id': u'Author6'},
 u'456': {'id': u'Author2'},
 u'789': {'id': u'Author3'}}
>>> G.node['111']
{'id': u'Author4'}
```

Moreover, the node id is a string, not an integer. If you need an integer, you may need to relabel the nodes.